# Batch processing DTM with Hillshade in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, batch, digital-image-processing, hillshade

I'm using the Hillshade tool from GDAL library [Raster analysis] in QGIS 3.4.

I can't use the batch process with creative options like `compress=LZW` or `profile=Geotif`. It doesn't work.

The tool works only an image for time. Has someone found the same problem?